# My alerts and form isn't redirecting when submit button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, https, recaptcha, addeventlistener

For some reason when my submit button is clicked, it does not redirect to the site, or have any alerts that tell me if username is empty, or password is invalid etc.... I have blocked out the recaptcha key for privacy reasons.
This is the html code

[HTML 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIxE2.png)
[HTML 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diGbC.png)

This is the javascript and html code

```js
document.getElementById('form').addEventListener("submit", handleFormSubmit);


function handleFormSubmit(event){

   event.preventDefault();



let Username = document.getElementById("username").value;
let Password = document.getElementById("password").value;
let reconfirmPassword= document.getElementById("ConfirmPassword").value;
let email = document.getElementById("email").value;
let reconfirmEmail = document.getElementById("reconfirmEmail").value;
let maleRadio = document.querySelector('input[value="male"]');
const femaleRadio = document.querySelector('input[value="female"]');


    if(Username === ''){
        alert("Please enter a username");
    }
    
    if(Username.length < 4){
        alert("Username is too short");
    }

    if(Password === ''){
        alert("Please enter a password");
    }
    if(Enzoic.currentPasswordScore < Enzoic.PASSWORD_STRENGTH.Medium){
        alert("Password not strong enough");
    }
    
    if(Password !== reconfirmPassword){
        alert("Passwords do not match");
    }

    if(reconfirmPassword !== Password){
        alert("Passwords do not match");
    }

    const regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/
    if(email === ''){
        alert("Please enter a email");
    } else if(!regex.test(email)){
        alert("Invalid email address");
    } else if( email != reconfirmEmail){
        alert("Email do not match")
    }

    if(reconfirmEmail !== email){
        alert("Email does not match");
    }

    if((!maleRadio.checked) && (!femaleRadio.checked)){
        alert("Please select a gender");
    }

    const recaptchaResponse = grecaptcha.getResponse();
    if(recaptchaResponse === ''){
        alert("Please complete the captcha");
    }
    

    window.location.replace('https://www.google.com');



}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<link href="/Merriweather_Sans/MerriweatherSans-VariableFont_wght.ttf">
<link href="fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Bold.ttf">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js">


function onSubmit(token) {
     document.getElementById("form").submit();
   }


</script>
<script async type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.enzoic.com/js/enzoic.min.js">
  </script>
  
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Create Your User</h1>
  </header>
<form id="form" method="post">
<label>Username</label>
<input type="name" id="username"/><br>
<br>
<label>Password</label>
<input type="password" id="password" enz-enable enz-theme='light'><br>
<br>
<label  id="confirmPassLabel">Reconfirm Password</label>
<input type="password" id="ConfirmPassword"><br>
<br>
<label for="email">Email</label>
<input type="name" id="email" type="email">
<div>
<label for="reconfirmEmail">Confirm email</label>
<input type="name" id="reconfirmEmail" type="email"><br>
<label>Male </label>
<input type="radio" id="male">
<label>Female</label>
<input type="radio" id="female">
<div  class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LeM8o4jAAAAAObqejc6i8IdWV15fTHM7w1ORVI7"></div>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"  id = "submit" class="g-recaptcha" 
data-sitekey="6Lf43Y4jAAAAADZXBGovIWO1DqYJStERrJxwg4Yj" 
data-callback='onSubmit' 
data-action='submit'>
<script src="formFunctions.js"></script>
</form>

</body>
```

This is the javascript code:

[[JAVASCRIPT]
[Javascript 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGj4f.png)

I tried seeing if the eventlistener at the top of the js file was a problem by just replacing the action after 'submit' to window.location.assign("https://somewebsite.com"). That worked but just linking everything up with the button is not working.